# Storing/Loading huge numpy array with less memory

Tags: python, numpy, ram

I have a numpy array of shape (20000, 600, 768). I need to store it, so later I could load it back to my code.
The main problem is memory usage when you load it back.
I have just 16GB RAM.

For example, I tried pickle. When it loads it all I almost have no memory left to do anything else. Especially to train the model.

I tried write and load back with hdf5 (h5py). Just a small piece (1000, 600, 768). But it seems like it "eats" even more memory.

Also tried csv.. That's just a no-no. Takes TOO much time to write data in.

Would be grateful for any suggestions how I could store my array so when I would load it back it wouldn't take that much memory.

P.S. The data I store is vector representation of texts which I later use for training my model.

Comment: An array with shape (20000, 600, 768)…  If i understand correctly that's 9.216.000.000 entries. That's gonna be big either way. Even if it is just that many boolean values, it's going to be just over a gigabyte of data. Besides, storing it doesn't make it magically smaller when you load it back in, it will always be the same size. Maybe try eliminating duplicate entries, null values and what not, if you haven't already done so?

Comment: There could be some ways if your matrix is sparse. Could you please comment on the array data?

Comment: @Chinni I store vector representations of texts.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do a lot of things.

First of all you can change the data format to be stored in different ways:

- in a file in your secondary memory to be read iteratively (dumping a python object on secondary memory is not efficient. You need to find a better format. For example a text file in which the lines are the rows of the matrix)
- or in a database. Always to make the data readable in an iterative manner.

Second, and most important, **you need to change your algorithm**. If you cannot fit all the data in memory, you need to use other kinds of methods, in which you use batchs of data instead of all the data.

For machine learning for example, there are a lot of methods in which you do incremental updates of the model with batchs of data

Third, there are method in which you can **reduce the dimensionality of your training set**. For example using methods like PCA, feature selection etc

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As far as I know.. If you don't train the model on all data at once it wouldn't train well (Like, first train on 5k examples.. Then train on top with another 5k etc.). So, you are probably talking about something else. May I ask to name some kinds of methods (for ML/DL) you were talking about? So I could google about them. That would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You can do also feature selection, to reduce the dimensionality.

Comment: Neural Network training can work in batchs (Multilayer Perceptron), for example.

Comment: I'm working with BERT vectors. So, the whole point is that the vectors would be d = 768. And.. I mean, of course the model uses batches (batch_size = 32). The problem is to store that much data in the memory to feed into network. It's just it seems like pickle loads memory even more...... Ahhh very confused..

Comment: you can read the data iteratively, like I said, and use train_batch method

Comment: pickle is not a good way to store your data, as I said before, because the data is loaded interely in memory. You need to change format